# Docker Engine don't start after the first installation in Windows 11

Tags: docker

I want to learn about Docker. So I go ahead to install Docker, check all requirements for Windows 11,

- **wsl2** is enabled in my system.
- **virtualization** is also enabled.
- I have 16gb ram

but I don't know why the docker engine don't start. Every time I see the following image [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98jea.png)

I have done so many things, I am listing all of them ---

- Execute the command `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon` by running command line as administrator but no effect.
- I watch from an youtube video that some time ubuntu installed in wsl2 make interruption in docker daemon, so I uninstall it. But still the problem persists.
- I installed hyper-v as there is no option for hyper-v in windows 11' s "turn windows features on or off" and enabled it. same problem exist.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling docker and restarting multiple times, but still no luck.

I don't know why this happened. Please help me in this matter. I have windows 11 home single language installed in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Windows 11, but the solution in the link below fixed it.

wsl --update

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11805#issuecomment-891528897